# How do I make template type deduction work with references?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

I have a template function, `func`:

```
template<typename T>
void func(T p)  { f(p); }
```

And a set of functions `f`:

```
f(SomeType&);
f(int);
...
```

If I instantiate the template function, `func`, using a reference as function argument `p`, without explicitly specifying template parameter `T`, then the type deduced will not be the reference type of `p`, but rather the type `p` is a reference to, for example:

```
SomeType s;
SomeType& ref_to_s = s;
func(ref_to_s);             // Type deduction results in: func<SomeType>(ref_to_s)
func<SomeType&>(ref_to_s);  // Need to explicitly specify type to work with reference
```

So, my questions are:

- Why does the compiler fail to deduce the reference type `SomeType&` in the above situation?
- Is there a way to define template function `func`, so that type deduction works with a reference type, without explicit specification of the template parameter `T`?

To be clear, I'd like something working with both (see functions `f` above):

```
func(ref_to_s);    // Calls func<SomeType&>(ref_to_s)
func(1);           // Calls func<int>(1)
```

Comment: Plainly, this is how template argument deduction works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer to the first part is that initializing an object from a value and binding a reference to a value are considered equally good (both are "exact matches" in overload resolution), and so the referenciness of a parameter is not deduced. Rather, you must specify it exactly. For a related example consider a hypothetical construction

```
T x = f();
```

where `T` is (for the duration of this thought experiment) something you're supposed to deduce. What should `x` be - an object, or a reference? What would it depend on? The expression on the right has a value, of course, and the type of that value is always an object type. How should you decide? You could query the value category of the expression, but that's too subtle. So instead, *you* have to say what you want:

```
T x = f();    // x is an object
T & r = f();  // r is a reference
```

In C++, this mechanism is actually available if you replace `T` with `auto`. The same rules apply to template argument deduction for function templates.

Now on to how to solve your problem. The usual idiom is to make the function template *always* take a reference, and then forward the argument to the inner call:

```
template <typename T>
void func(T && t)
{
    f(std::forward<T>(t));
};
```

Now `func`'s parameter is always a reference in any specialization (but thanks to a weird rule called "reference collapsing" it can be either an lvalue or an rvalue reference), and that value is forwarded *with the same value category group* to `f`, and this overload resolution on `f` allows lvalue-reference overloads to be selected when the original argument for `func` was an lvalue.

Comment: Universal reference and reference collapsing are now more clear to me; thanks a lot for your detailed answer.

Comment: "The expression on the right has a value, of course, and the type of that value is always an object type."
And what if f() returns a reference?

Comment: @bipll: There's no such thing. A function call expression *is an expression*, and expressions always have object types. The reference qualification on the function return type determines the value category of the expression. A function cannot "return a reference", that's just a sloppy colloquialism.

Comment: "expression always have object types". Except when they dont: `void()` and `*[]{}` both don't have object types. The first's type is `void` and the second's type is `void()`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't understand the three yesses. I have only made two points that need to be confirmed. Or is the first "yes" something of an overall "yes"?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Sorry, I was being facetious. It was meant as an "I know, but don't want to go into details". I didn't want to complicate the my point with other kinds of expressions, and I wanted the lesson to be that expressions are never references. You're right of course that there are several kinds of types an expression can have.

Comment: @KerrekSB don't worry, haha. I'm just kidding :p

Answer (score 7):

Use forwarding-reference:

```
template<typename T>
void func(T && p)    //notice &&
{ 
    f(std::forward<T>(p));  //notice std::forward
}
```

Now please search forwarding-reference (or *universal-reference* as it is previously referred to) as well as `std::forward` on this site to know more about them.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the following example:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T value, T& ref) {// fake swapping
T temp = ref;
ref = value;
value = temp;
}
```

When compiler tries to deduce the type of T, the reasonable thing to do is firstly removing possible references from "value" and "ref", so that

```
int i = 1; 
int j = 2;
f(i, j);    //value of j becomes 1.
//up to here, value of i is still 1
```

Otherwise, things will get pretty bizarre. If T is otherwise deduced to T&,  the type of f(i, j) will be then equivalent with f(int&, int& &). Assuming T& & collapsing to T&, then it becomes f(int&, int&). This is totally against the programmer's intention.